# use azure credentials in web requests

Tags: powershell, office365api

I need to create a solution to download the usage reports on a scheduled basis from here: https://reports.office.com/pbi/v1.0/{tenantid}/UserActivity

This should be as simple as:

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'reportingserviceaccount'
$uri = "https://reports.office.com/pbi/v1.0/{tenantid}/UserActivity"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -OutFile C:\users\Public\output.json
```

or

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -OutFile C:\users\Public\output.json
```

However, both cases I only get the login form downloaded instead of the data. When I open the url in my browser I can correctly see the json response. Can somebody give me a hint what am I missing?

Comment: That would work for basic authentication. You need to use Oauth. You can accomplish that in a few different ways. The key point is you need to obtain an authorization token that you will put in your headers `-Headers= @{'Authorization'="Bearer $YourToken"}` 

You can do it using App / Secret (so it's 100%) transparent or have the user login through a Oauth window and get the token, which you will include in your api calls. That's quite complicated when doing it for the first time.

Comment: I don't have a ready sample nor the time to answer right now so  I will let someone else provide an answer... Here's the way that will prompt a credential window (it should work in your scenario if you work from that example). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ronba/using-powershell-and-the-office-365-rest-api-with-oauth

Comment: Hm, to trying this application thing, but looks like I need to add some extra permissions to the app (I already added ActivityReports.Read from Office 365 Management APIs and Reports.Read.All from Graph, but they didn't help) and I don't really know what.

Comment: Looks like this my issue is permission related. I'll post another question and delete this one.